# Recommended way to add polyfills depending on a list of supported browsers

Tags: performance, bundle, babeljs, webpack-4, polyfills

We're using webpack and I am looking for the best way to add the polyfills required for a certain list of browsers in a Multi page application.

We have a list of browsers with the minimum supported versions like:

- IE 11
- Chrome 65
- Firefox 66

and we would like webpack to add the polyfills required for this versions based on the functionalities we are using in the code.

I.E if we are using promises then webpack will identify that and add the polyfill for promises only because of IE 11 and so on...

What is the current state of on demand polyfilling like this?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You likely are looking for [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) and [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) - both have pretty great documentation on how they work together.